# Canon SL3 and Godox V1

Tags: canon, troubleshooting, off-camera-flash, camera, godox

I have searched to find an answer for one of my students and need help. Will the Godox V1 and Godox trigger work with the Canon SL3. Nikon is

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell which 3rd party flashes are compatible with Canon's SL3 missing pin hot shoe mount?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129417/how-can-i-tell-which-3rd-party-flashes-are-compatible-with-canons-sl3-missing-p)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, none of the Godox for-Canon speedlights are compatible with the SL3 when used directly on the hotshoe of the camera, (but reports are contradictory and confusing). Unfortunately, the firmware updates that added compatibility with the T7/2000D and T100/4000D hotshoes do not work with the SL3/250D.

The V1-C works fine as an off-camera flash with full compatibility, since all the Godox **transmitters** have been firmware updated for SL3/250D hotshoe compatibility.

If you need on-camera compatibility with a V1C, you need to get an X2T-C transmitter, and stack that in-between the flash and the camera a hotshoe.

The best option for an SL3 user who needs an on-camera flash is to probably look at the Canon OEM options, such as the EL-100 or a 430EX II, 600EX II-RT or EL-1. Avoid the EL-5, since that only works with EOS R bodies that have the new multifunction hotshoe.